# Find filenames difference between two directories (ignoring filename extension)

Tags: text-processing, files, coreutils

I have a lot of files that I need to keep in sync as example:

```
./regular/*.txt
./compressed/*.txt.bz2
```

When files get uploaded to ./regular I want to make a script to periodically check and bzip2 compress the files that are not already compressed.

In my head it is something like...

```
ls ./regular/*.txt as A
ls ./compressed/*.txt* as B

for each in A as file
    if B does not contain 'file' as match
        bzip2 compress and copy 'file' to ./compressed/
```

Is there a program out there that can do this, or someone who can show how this kind of thing is done in coreutils / bash?

Comment: A "file type" in Unix are things like "regular file", "symbolic link", "directory" etc. Do you mean "filename suffix"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`:

```
regular=(regular/*.txt(N:t))
compressed=(compressed/*.txt.bz2(N:t:r))
print -r Only in regular: ${regular:|compressed}
print -r Only in compressed: ${compressed:|regular}
```

Then you can do:

```
for f (${regular:|compressed}) bzip2 -c regular/$f > compressed/$f.bz2
```

That's using the `${A:|B}` array subtraction operator (expands to the elements of `A` *bar* (excluding) those of `B`).

With `bash` and GNU tools:

```
(
  export LC_ALL=C
  shopt -s nullglob
  comm -z23 <(cd regular && set -- *.txt && (($#)) && printf '%s\0' "$@") \
            <(cd compressed && set -- *.txt.bz2 && (($#)) &&
               printf '%s\0' "${@%.bz2}")
) |
  while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
    bzip2 -c "regular/$f" > "compressed/$f.bz2"
  done
```

The subtraction being then performed by the `comm` command. Here using NUL delimiters to be able to cope with arbitrary file names like in the zsh solution.

Answer (score 0):

just change your directories path with no "/" at the end, hope it helps!

```
#!/bin/bash

path_input=/tmp/regular
path_compressed=/tmp/compressed
compressed_ext='.bz2'

echo "Starting backup..."
#List files and check if they are compressed
for file in `ls -1 $path_input/*.txt`; do

    #Compressed file search
    search_compressed=`sed "s;"$path_input";"$path_compressed";g" <<< $file$compressed_ext`

    if [[ ! -f $search_compressed ]]
        #Compress file
        then
            echo "Compressing $file"
            bzip2 --keep --force "$file"
            mv -f "$file$compressed_ext" "$path_compressed"
    fi
done

echo "Done"
```